# How do I initialize HighChart series values with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to dynamically initialize my HighChart series values before first data point is requested using ajax. I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong or if what I'm trying is even possible. Can someone please take a look and help?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: requestData
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Test'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 100,
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Test'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        series: [{
            //AJAX NOT WORKING HERE
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function() {
                var data = [];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/test/random2.php",
                    data: "p=2",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function(result){
                        var values = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
                        var time = (new Date()).getTime();
                        for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                            data.push({
                                x: time + i * 60000,
                                y: values[i+19];
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
                return data;})
        }]
    });        
});
```

**UPDATED CODE**
Here is my working solution

```
    function doHighChart(data) {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline',
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: requestData
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Test'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 100,
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Test'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: data
        }]
    });        
}

    $(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/test/random2.php",
        data: "p=2",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(result){
            var values = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
            var time = (new Date()).getTime();
            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                //data.push([i, -i]);
                //data.push("{x:" + (time + i * 1000) ", y: " + values[i+19] + "}");
                data.push([
                    time + i * 1000,
                    values[i+19]
                ]);
            }
            doHighChart(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think that can works. At the moment the js code is executed, data will be empty. You can put your chart declaration in a function with the serie datas as param. Then call your ajax on the page onload and call you chart function when you have the result, passing the result datas as param.

Comment: Highchart doc have a ajax example too if you prefer : http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-ajax/

Comment: thank you, I'm now able to initialize my data series with ajax (updated code above). however my initial data series is not connected and then connects after all the initial points have gone away. can you also shed some light on that for me? thanks

Comment: i got the dots connected, my data that was loaded into the function wasn't properly labeled to link them in the graph (labels: x and y). so just make sure you're json array is labeled with those {x: foo, y: bar}

Answer (score 0):

You need to call $.ajax() and in callback initialise your chart.